# Preventing Edge from showing the visual search icon when users hover over an image

Tags: html, css

Microsoft Edge have recently added a new hover icon (visual search) to all images over a certain size on a webpage (it seems to show for all images above ~180px).

The user can remove it in Edge settings, but I'm looking for a solution in HTML/CSS to prevent this icon from showing when hovering over an img tag.

**What the icon looks like**

[image: This is the icon]

**Icon after hover**

[image: icon expanded on hover]

**An animated GIF showing the hover behavior**

[image]

Comment: From the company that bought you "Clippy"

Comment: lol good luck, I'm sure Microsoft has made it very possible to remove

Comment: See what is its tag on developer mode and if it has any class or id then set the class display to none in CSS. I am using same version in windows 11 but this feature is not available even in the setting.

Comment: @Mehrwarz No class is applied to the element so it must be done out of the scope of the DOM.

Comment: I cannot at the moment reproduce this - in my Edge Settings under appearance>visualSearch I see 'If this is on, you can hover over an image to explore more related content about the things you see in the image. For now, visual search only works on a few sites. We're working on expanding our supported sites list.' I suspect there is nothing you can do at the HTML/CSS level to alter the setting but could you tell us what site this is showing on? I have the same Edge version.

Comment: @JonP Indeed! This is a dangerous precedent they are setting with this. No browser should alter the site owners UI.

Comment: @AHaworth First noticed it this morning when working on my project locally on PC. Noticed it on some other news websites but seems to be rather erratic. Also https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/  and my local site shows constantly.

Comment: I still can't see it even on the developer microsoft site (I've checked Edge settings and have visualSearch on). I'm still on Windows10 is that a difference from your set up?

Comment: @AHaworth Possibly... I was kinda forced onto Windows 11.

Comment: For what it's worth in see it in Win 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using pointer-events:none on my image, but it still kept showing up on mouse hover.  I eventually gave up using the IMG tag altogether, and used a DIV container instead, and then loaded the image as a background image. Apparently, background images don't trigger the visual menu.

```html
<DIV style = 'background-image:url("path to image"); background-size:100% 100%;'>
</DIV>
```

Comment: This is definitely not accessible or best practice and as Mike mentioned fails when background graphics are disabled

Comment: @Zach Jensz - Explain what you mean by "definitely not accessible".  I think I answered the actual question just fine. If you have a better coding solutuon, then let's see it.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use `pointer-events: none;` for image

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've just found out that this 'feature' must have been removed as the issue is no longer present.

Comment: This does work. However in the long run it’s not a satisfactory answer (and I mean Microsoft needs to make a better solution) because that’s not what pointer events is meant to be for. I’d consider this a temporary workaround and as such it should be applied with a class .disable-visual-search { pointer-events: none; }. That way it’s much easier to undo later.

Comment: See also https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2345

Comment: It works great! I put it in the user styles using an Edge extension (Stylus), and the buttons disappeared! The were just behind the "next" button in a slideshow, so I hit it like 100 times per day by accident. Used `.slider img { pointer-events: none; }`!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the best way to fix this issue is to do something like the following:

```html
<style>
    .no-visual-search {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
<div class='img-container'>
    <img class='no-visual-search'>
</div>
```

Then you can place your pointer-events that you need in the `img-container` div, and make the sizes of the div and the img equal.

I ran into the same problem and really wish there was a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Now there are browser settings which can remove the icons.

To hide the icons:

- Type the URL `edge://settings/appearance/hoverMenu`
- or *Settings* > *Appearance* > *Visual search*
- or search "visual search" in the settings menu

There are two options, one
which shows the icons permanently and the other on hover and then
users can also prevent it from showing on selected sites.
[image]

I wasn't able to disable it via the code. My images are svg so the feature doesn't even work anyway!

Comment: I don't have option in settings. It seems to have completely been removed. Weird! (Version 102.0.1245.44)

Comment: My version: Version 102.0.1245.44 (Official build) (64-bit)
I don't see why it wouldn't work for you.  I pasted an image... You search and then click on the result to access the options

Comment: yeah that's the weird part that doesn't show for me. 
https://imgur.com/oSNpmpx

Comment: I found the option to disable it by going into the hover menu section. Opening this link in Edge should bring you straight to the option. edge://settings/appearance/hoverMenu?search=visual%20search

This is on Edge 110.0.1587.69

Comment: The question is asking for a solution to disable it in the page, not in user settings. I assume that there is a case where designer needs to disable visual search for a particular element on a page rather than rely on user's preferences in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried "setting the background-image in the style" method, and it works, but I find that the image does not print unless the print background graphics setting under more settings is checked.

```html
<DIV style = 'background-image:url("path to image"); background-size:100% 100%;'></DIV>
```

I fooled around a bit and tried to have two images, one to print and one for the screen, but that seemed too much.

So, I have found a way that will show the image on the screen and printing using this method. This is for an image that is 200x100 pixels.

```html
<IMG style='content:url("path to image")' width='200' height='100' alt='Alternate text' title='Some sort of title'>
```

Now I have images that show without that stupid visual search icon on Microsoft Edge.

Comment: This is definitely not accessible or best practice but if that's the trade off you're willing to make that's up to you

Comment: Sorry about the non-accessibility. I forget to use the IMG tag and alt and title attributes.

Comment: @Mike McCollister - Most browsers won't print background images, and have been that way for decades. Kudos for finding something that works. The real problem is Microsoft. Seems like they want to go the way of Netscape Navigator......

Answer (score -2):

Looks like Microsoft have learnt the error of their ways as now they have either removed this 'feature' or set it to off by default. I can't find any settings for it so I assume it's been removed... for now!

Comment: I don't believe this to be the case . it shows up on my website and I haven't enabled this.

Comment: @PanamaJack Odd as it just stopped appearing for me I didn't change anything. What version of Edge are you on?

Comment: Version 102.0.1245.33 (Official build) (64-bit).. MS always finds away to p!ss off devs no matter what browser they make. lol.  That feature is so intrusive to your website.

Comment: I did a clean install of window four days ago and it’s most definitely enabled by default. (Unless it’s somehow got stuck on and saved in my settings in the cloud). Highly intrusive - it’s trying to send people to Toyota’s website when people hover over images of my razor blade.