# Microsoft Edge, shows image search upon hovering

Tags: microsoft-edge

While, testing a webpage on Edge recently, I noticed that upon hovering over an image, Edge shows a menu like this.

[image]

This is not in Chrome or Firefox and is only present in Edge. I want to know, how can I remove this, via code so that my webpage doesn't show this ?

Comment: Which Edge version are you talking about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent Edge from showing the visual search icon when users hover over an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731966/how-do-i-prevent-edge-from-showing-the-visual-search-icon-when-users-hover-over)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to check the image you posted and it looks like the feature **Visual Search**.

Visual search lets you quickly explore more related content about products, landmarks, celebrities, animals or plants you see in an image.

If you are using an older version of the Edge browser then try to update it to the latest version and check for the issue. Some users have reported that they are not facing the said issue in the latest version of the Edge browser.

I would suggest you try to add the code below to your image may help to avoid it.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

If you manually want to disable that feature then you could add `edge://settings/appearance/visualSearch` in the address bar and press the Enter key.

disable the option, '**Show visual search on image hover**'.

[image]

Helpful Reference:

1. [How do I prevent Edge from showing the visual search icon when users hover over an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731966/how-do-i-prevent-edge-from-showing-the-visual-search-icon-when-users-hover-over)