# Microsoft Edge Visual Search prevents dragging image

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, microsoft-edge

Since Microsoft Edge Version 120 something for Visual Search has changed which breaks dragging a image within my Angular Web App.

The img Element has the property `draggable="true"`.
If someone tries to move fast with the mouse the dragging works, but with normal mouse behavior as soon as the Visual Search icon in the to right corner appears in the image the dragging anywhere on the img Element is not working.

Disabling the Visual Search within the settings solves the problem, but is no viable solution for all visitors.
Other Browser like Chrome keep working fine.
I already send Microsoft Edge Feedback with the three dot menu.
I don't think it's a bug because Edge Beta Version 122 has the same Problem.
Using `pointer-events: none;` like mentioned in the [question: Preventing Edge from showing the visual search icon when users hover over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731966/preventing-edge-from-showing-the-visual-search-icon-when-users-hover-over-an-ima) did hide the icon but dragging is still broken.

Is there a way programatically to tell Edge not to show Visual Search for my App entirely or tell Edge some other way that the image has to be draggble?
(I don't want to replace the img element with something like background image as workaround for accessibility reasons)

**Update Reproducible Example**:
Domain: `http://test123.local/`
HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html title="MicrosoftEdgeVisualSearch" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MicrosoftEdgeVisualSearch</title>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("data", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("data");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Drag the image into the rectangle:</p>
    <div style="width: 350px;height: 350px;border: 1px solid black;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>
    <img id="drag1"
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1122px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png"
        draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="350" height="350">
</body>

</html>
```

to make it work:

- no localhost/ip/stackblitz domain
- image has to be larger than somewhere around 180px
- default Microsoft Edge settings

**Update 2**
I hadn't time to originally attatch a gif of the effect.
If i try to reproduce it now it magically works again.
Seems like Edge got an Update?

Added gifs in case the problem appears again in the future.

The working state:
[image: working as expected]

---

The issue:
[image: dragging not working]

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce your problem, I created the example locally and tested it, and it doesn't show up with this visual search option, and it works fine using jquery.ui drag api. If possible, can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I tried to create a stackblitz.com example but i cannot reproduce it there (i fail at the first step display image with Visual Search Icon in to right corner).
Then i tried a simple html file same...
I checked the App hosted within my local enviroment and not reproduceable!
I am 99% sure the Code at both places is the same.
Maybe Edge has special behavior for some sites like ip/localhost/stackblitz?
Update: Yes, I used a Reverse Proxy (caddy) to use another domain (http://test123.local/) for the local hosted index.html file and now i am able to reproduce the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the test result.I found that if add the style `pointer-events: none;`, Edge behaves the same as in Chrome, requiring the image to be dragged twice to work.

And I found that the drag api in jquery UI has good compatibility with it, and the problem you mentioned will not occur because of the visual search option. Something like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MicrosoftEdgeVisualSearch</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dragImg").draggable();
            $("#droppable").droppable({
                accept: "#dragImg",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var droppable = $(this);
                    var draggable = ui.draggable;
                    // Move draggable into droppable
                    draggable.appendTo(droppable);
                    draggable.css({ top: '0px', left: '0px' });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Test Page..</h3>
    <br />
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="width:350px;height:350px;border:1px solid blue">
        <img id="dragImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1122px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png" width="350" height="350" alt="Alternate Text" draggable="true" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header" style="width:350px;height:350px;border:1px solid blue">
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Maybe you could give it a try and let me know if it fits your needs.

Comment: Adding `pointer-events: none;` does not work as expected.  
You can drag it the secound time but cannot drop it.  
Originally dragging worked as expected the first time in both Browsers always.  
Suddenly over night (Edge Update) all clients accessing with the new Edge Version cound't drag even after a secound or more times at all if the Visual Search Icon was visible (enabled). If a user was super fast and started dragging before the icon appeared (<100ms passed) the dragging and dropping still worked. Thanks for the example but i do not want to include jquery within my app. (see Update 2)