# onmouseover event suddenly not working in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have the following code throughout my site to swap images on hover:

```
<img class="rounded-lg object-cover shadow-lg transition hover:scale-[1.05]"
src="/assets/profiles/leadership/volker-photo-detail-hover.png"
onmouseover="this.src='/assets/profiles/leadership/volker-photo-detail-hover.png';"
onmouseout="this.src='/assets/profiles/leadership/volker-photo-detail.png';">
```

which has been working fine for the last year, but suddenly it won't work correctly in Microsoft Edge browser. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox. You can test here: https://jwmdrc.org/ (work in progress so not really accessible on smaller screens/mobiles yet) in different browsers and see that it's only Edge that is affected.

Maybe this is due to a recent update? Has anyone else encountered this and/or know of a solution?

Thanks

Edit: built with Statamic and Tailwind

Comment: This looks like it's using some sort of templating library which would be worth mentioning, and please make sure you include a [mre] in the question itself, users shouldn't need to visit an external site to see the issue.

Comment: (Don't universities usually have quite high standards in terms of usability and accessibility? You got images there that transport _text content_, and do have not even an `alt` text set. There would be _so much_ better solutions to achieve this ... just sayin'.)

Comment: yeah, it's still a work in progress, content and images subject to change so no alt txt set yet; had to go live earlier than I would have liked

Comment: I don't see any difference in behaviour between Firefox 115.5.0esr and Edge 118.0.2088.122 when I hover the mouse over the pictures. Maybe you can describe "won't work correctly" a bit more in detail?

Comment: yes, that's right, thanks @Krampus - the image changes on hover but then doesn't change back. It's pretty sporadic though; sometimes it changes, mostly it doesn't, it's sometimes delayed... it's very strange (my version is 120.0.2210.61)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conflict with Edge Visual Search**

The problem is caused by an Edge feature called "Visual Search" that adds a search icon to images on hover.

**Hover Problem**

The problem can be reproduced by visiting the [site](https://jwmdrc.org/) and moving the mouse across an image link. The image changes on hover, but does not change back to the original image after the mouse leaves.

[image: To reproduce the problem,]

Now open Edge settings and type "Visual Search". Expand the "Hover menu" section and disable "Show hover menu on image hover". When retesting the hover link, it now works as expected and like other browsers.

**Edge Settings**

[image]

If you can't find the setting, because you're using another language, visit [`edge://settings/appearance/hoverMenu`](https://edge://settings/appearance/hoverMenu) and uncheck the first option.

**More details**

There does not appear to be a way to disable Visual Search programmatically. The icon is displayed over images when certain, unknown, conditions are met. For example, it doesn't appear to get triggered within iframes (snippets, jsfiddle, etc.). And it only affects Windows versions of Edge from v95. This specific problem with feature "may" have been fixed in version 120.0.2210.77.

**Related question:**

[Preventing Edge from showing the visual search icon when users hover over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731966/preventing-edge-from-showing-the-visual-search-icon-when-users-hover-over-an-ima)

Comment: Note that the related question does not solve the issue. Adding `pointer-events: none` will completely disable all pointer events, not just Edge events. I haven't tested this, but you might have to wrap your images and assign the events to the wrapper.

Comment: Wow @Krampus what an excellent, thorough and comprehensive answer - thank you!

Comment: @3limin4t0r that's prefect, thank you for your advice - I'll look into implementing that change

Comment: @JohnDawson You could also try to use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. The difference with `mousehover` and `mouseout` is that the [events don't bubble up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event#usage_notes). But since you don't use that feature anyway, you can simply replace the events and keep the code the same.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @3limin4t0r, I'll give that a try. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Use "mouseover" Instead of "onmouseover".

Comment: That is the name of the event, not the name of the inline attribute.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).